# Can't mport javafx

Tags: javafx, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2.  I used the wizard to created a Java class library project so I could share a class among several projects. I now want to add some capability that requires me to import from javafx (SimpleStringProperty).  Fix imports didn't work and Intellisense says it doesn't know javafx.

I looked at the Project Properties | Libraries setting of one of my JavaFX applications and I see javafx.classpath.extension.  I think I need this, but I don't know how to add it.  I searched and someone suggested adding the jdk's jfxrt.jar file to the compile libraries, but that didn't work.

Is the lack of javafx.classpath.extension my problem?  If so, how do I add it?

Comment: What JDK do you use? I just tried this out (same Netbeans version) and it automatically added `jfxrt.jar` to the `JDK 1.8 (Default)` library item.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this bug that addresses this:  [Bug 213219](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213219) .

Basically, you:  "...go to Project Properties, Deployment panel, and check "Keep JavaFX Runtime on Classpath"..."

Thanks everyone!